# What is this fitting called (sketch)

Tags: plumbing-fixture

[image]

Can someone tell me the name of this fitting? I presume it is steel about 10mm x 25mm x 10mm with a threaded hole on the bottom.

Has holes all the way through on alternate faces.

Comment: Whats the fitting used for and where? Could you provide some context?

Comment: Unfortunately not. All I know is I found it near brass fittings in a Leyland shop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly typical basin waste ...

[image]

See where those rods intersect, there's a clamping block there.

Some people call it a *"Basin Waste Arm Pop Up Rod Link Connector Metal Linkage"* - but that's a bit verbose.